# How to embedd youtube playlist?

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube-api, html5-video

I implementing a site where i want to embedd a youtube videos playlist and i want to show like this - http://www.youtube.com/user/icicibank/home - using HTML5, javascript and youtube api. So how should i implement youtube playlist like above example ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to embed youtube videos as playlist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16114615/how-to-embed-youtube-videos-as-playlist)

Answer (score 1):

That appears to be a custom design that's distinct from the standard YouTube List Player embed. (If you want to see what the standard embed looks like, [this blog post](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2012/03/new-player-options-for-lists-of-videos.html) has an example.)

I don't think anyone here could give you exact instructions on how to replicate someone else's design. That's really outside the scope of Stack Overflow.