# How to embed youtube videos as playlist

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I have numerous youtube video clips, and I was wondering if it is possible to embed them on the site as youtube playlist, so that the next video starts playing automatically once the clip finishes. Is there such functionality either with YouTube API or without. If not possible, what would be the best approach. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you just embed a youtube playlist? Like Youtube Site explains: http://www.youtube.com/youtubeonyoursite

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/v/1ne-Q_YnDyo?version=3&loop=1&playlist=1ne-Q_YnDyo,x3PhrkkkzXg I wanted to embed it like that. It is not a simple video embed, i want to embed all the videos as a single playlist so that once the first video finishes playing, the next one starts automatically. Thanks though

Comment: but when you choose to embed a youtube playlist and selecting "from first" option, it starts automatically.

Comment: I actually don't have any playlist created in youtube. So, I want to actually create the playlist on the fly, for example if the user wants to play all the comedy clips, it will get all the video id of the comedy youtube videos from the database, then create a playlist for the user on the fly, so that he can watch the clips continuously. Sorry if my question sounded pretty ambiguous

Answer (score 42):

Actually there are two ways to embed playlists from youtube.
 In the first method you can directly specify all the videos that you want to play in the embed player.

```
<iframe width="720" height="405" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEO_ID?playlist=VIDEOID_1,VIDEOID_2"frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
```

Each video ID must be separated by using comma.

Secondly, you can embed a playlist that is already present in youtube using the playlist ID

```
<iframe width="720" height="405" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/?listType=playlist&list=PLAYLIST_ID" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I used the 2nd method. And we can also use `&index=0` or `&index=3` etc to change which video of the playlist is ready to play.

Comment: The second method doesn't seem to work anymore. Can anyone confirm?

Comment: @twigmac The second method works as well - https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#list

Comment: I confirm. The second method still works to this day.

Comment: The second method still works in 2021

Comment: The second method works as of 10 Feb 2022.

Answer (score 11):

I found the solution,

```
http://www.youtube.com/v/PRIMARYVIDEO_ID?version=3&loop=1&playlist=VIDEO_ID1,VIDEO_ID2
```

Where the VIDEO_ID1, and VIDEO_ID2... are the videos i want to include in the playlist.

Comment: This downloads some file! Careful

Comment: This can download a swf (flash) file, generally because the browser doesn't handle the request properly.

Answer (score 6):

https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo

```html
<iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="100%" height="405"
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/?listType=playlist&list=PL590L5WQmH8eYTXiTTjzo4YnK7vkCqZTI"
frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
```

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: @drew.. Check this http://prntscr.com/muejs5 and confirm please.

Comment: The original poster was asking about creating a list of videos on-the-fly and playing them, not creating and using a playlist, thus my comment.  the on-the-fly implementation is stunningly disjoint given the size of youtube.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use embedded playlists.

Here is an example of one of my playlists!

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=PLZtX_kbNpbDjYSUj-huH5pOKxifUNDi1O" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

In addition you could use the [Javascript Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference) to create custom behavior.

Comment: This does not answer the question asked.

Answer (score 2):

From the youtube [docs](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/171780?hl=en)

**Embed a playlist**

1. Sign in to your YouTube account on a computer.
2. On the left side of
   the page, select the playlist you want to embed.
3. Copy the playlist ID from the URL.
4. Modify the embed code for an individual video by doing the following: In the place of the video ID (after "embed/"), substitute "videoseries?list=". Then paste the playlist ID after the "=".
5. Paste the code into your blog or website HTML.

**Example:**

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=PLx0sYbCqOb8TBPRdmBHs5Iftvv9TPboYG" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: This does not answer the question.