# Embedded YouTube playlists are not accessible

Tags: html, youtube

Today I noticed that embedded YouTube playlists (video series) are not accessible on my website. Last week it worked perfectly. The playlists are present on YouTube, but the link in the embedded version is broken.

**My questions:**

1. Is this a known issue?
2. How to fix it? (How to make embedding code working again?)

Note: there is no issue with embedded videos just with playlists.

---

Example. I'm trying to embed the playlist
https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLLE8FSeLAY2on4zMQrrmFEIVjTzQfS6qt

The main steps to generate this embedding code are illustrated below:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=PLLE8FSeLAY2on4zMQrrmFEIVjTzQfS6qt" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

When I try to create embedding code on YouTube (Fig. 1., Fig. 2), it seems that there is an issue as the picture of the first video is missing (Fig. 3), and when I hover the mouse over "Watch on YouTube" the link displayed at the bottom left corner on my browser is incorrect  (Fig. 4).

[image]
Fig. 1

[image]
Fig. 2

[image]
Fig. 3

[image]
Fig. 4

Comment: As usual, Google screwing around and making unnecessary and unwanted changes only to justify their paychecks. I guess they don't realize that they've just broken millions of webpages, including their own help pages and as show in the question, even YouTube's own embedding function. ¬_¬

Comment: This is insane. So much content is broken across the web right now because of this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems Google made a few updates. In your embed code if you replace `videoseries?` with `playlist?` then that should work.

Comment: This worked (for now).  I checked Google's help pages and they still use *videoseries*. Where did you find the information? 

Comment: Here I am trying to decide if I should fix the embed code or if google screwed up an is going to revert.  has anyone stumbled upon any info to answer that.

Comment: While this gets my embedded playlists to display properly, I still get playback errors when attempting to actually play the videos.

Answer (score 0):

are you embedding the link of the whole playlist or first video of that playlist. embedding the first playlist video into iframe tag works fine for me and displays the whole playlist.
Check out the
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fD6Ea.png)
. Moreover for further study check this post.
[How to embed youtube videos as playlist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16114615/how-to-embed-youtube-videos-as-playlist)

Comment: Even my answer is correct, still you are giving negative votes. Could you exolain whats wrong in my answer

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion of a workaround. P.S. It's not me, who gives negative votes. And my upvote could only remove the downvote.

Comment: Its okay, i am very thankful to you for your upvote. Happy coding mate

Answer (score 0):

you need to replace "videoseries" in the embed code (URL) with "playlist"